# Using geometric construction, is there a way to construct a circle that spins another circle at 3:2 ratio?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I have been tinkering with GeoGebra to construct a point on a circle that I can move around the circumference which then in turn moves another point on another circle at a slower rotation rate (specifically 3:2)? 
All I can do is to make it match the same rotation rate.

You can see the set up for that in the image below. All it is showing is as I move point "E" around the circle at the origin point "H" travels the same path in a different spot.

[image]

Comment: Probably off-topic for this group, since it's really a software support question. In particuluar, "which then in turn..." implies some linkage between two different points that is not at all clear from the picture, nor how a linkage is created.

Comment: This is easily achieved by using the Geometers Sketchpad.

Comment: I don't believe it is off topic at all, i am asking to to geometrically construct a mechanism. You could possibly describe this utilizing a compass and straightedge.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do that with a purely geometric construction. After a full revolution point $E$ comes back to where it started from, so its final position is indistinguishable from the initial position, but point $H$ will not return to its initial position. In other words: the map $E\mapsto H$ is not a geometrical function, you need some mechanism to count how many revolutions have been made "since the beginning".

It is possible however that some trick may do the job, either with GeoGebra or some other software.